# FCM XMPP: no 'success' response

Tags: node.js, firebase, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using nodejs to implement a server application with XMPP. I am following the [guide to authorize an XMPP connection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server?#authorize_an_xmpp_connection.). My problem is exactly when I expect a

```
<success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>
```

when I send the server key, a SASL PLAIN authentication. It is made this way

```
const key = Buffer('\x00' + senderId + '@gcm.googleapis.com\x00' + serverKey).toString('base64');
const message = `<auth mechanism="PLAIN"
xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">${key}</auth>`;
```

Where *senderID* is that number that is in "Cloud Messaging" tag and
*serverKey* is one of the server keys from the "Cloud Messaging" tag. There are two server keys types: one is the "normal" and the other one is inherited; I've used both types without success.

I don't really know what I am doing wrong, or what I am missing.

The first two steps of the connection, the 'hello' and the list of mechanisms response from FCM are done. However, after this, FCM closes the connection. I suspect is related with this problem.

I would appreciate a help. Thanks.

Comment: I am using the testing endpoint fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com:5236

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted with the Firebase support team and they have solved my problem (thanks a lot).

The thing, with nodejs, is you have to avoid to implement the event 'end' on the socket because this seems to force to close the socket, and use the same socket. Another thing is to avoid set up the socket encoding. You can convert the buffer with another encoding though.
With all this I can mark this question as solved.